# How set UV channel scale in program [SceneKit Xcode]

Tags: ios, scenekit, texture-mapping

In SceneKit, I want to apply a small texture on whole surface of an object, but the texture is stretched to cover, not piled as blocks. Like this

[image]

and this is what i want:

[image]

Then i find you can set uv channel's scale to 6 or bigger to make the texture piled together. As following:

[image]

Does framework supply some api to set the property in program ?
I googled a lot and no lucks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the corresponding API is on SCNMaterialProperty:

```
/*! 
 @property contentsTransform
 @abstract Determines the receiver's contents transform. Animatable.
 */
@property(nonatomic) SCNMatrix4 contentsTransform;
```

Comment: great! thank you @Toyos. anyway, this name is really not intuitive!  hard to connect them two together...

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNMaterialProperty_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNMaterialProperty/contentsTransform) are a bit clearer. Always good to read those, not just the headers.